# Exception: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started when using Spring `@DynamicPropertySource`

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, testcontainers

I tried to upgrade my tests to use TestConainers and Spring `@DynamicPropertySource`.

```java
    @Container
    static Neo4jContainer<?> neo4jContainer = new Neo4jContainer<>("neo4j:4.0")
            .withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(5));

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void neo4jProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("org.neo4j.driver.uri", neo4jContainer::getBoltUrl);
        registry.add("org.neo4j.driver.authentication.username", () -> "neo4j");
        registry.add("org.neo4j.driver.authentication.password", neo4jContainer::getAdminPassword);
    }
```

When I ran [the sample test](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/boot-data-neo4j-rx/src/test/java/com/example/demo/PostRepositoryWithTestContainersTest.java) and got the following exceptions, it seems the Neo4j docker is not ready when the tests is started.

```sh
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.neo4j.driver.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.DriverConfiguration.neo4jDriver
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:126) ~[spring-boot-test-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:336) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:252) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:251) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$before$0(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:184) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:183) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:77) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:132) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Mapped port can only be obtained after the container is started
    at org.testcontainers.shaded.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:174) ~[testcontainers-1.10.7.jar:na]
    at org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerState.getMappedPort(ContainerState.java:105) ~[testcontainers-1.10.7.jar:na]
    at org.testcontainers.containers.Neo4jContainer.getBoltUrl(Neo4jContainer.java:114) ~[neo4j-1.10.7.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DynamicValuesPropertySource.getProperty(DynamicValuesPropertySource.java:43) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:85) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:62) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:535) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition$Spec.collectProperties(OnPropertyCondition.java:140) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition$Spec.access$000(OnPropertyCondition.java:105) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition.determineOutcome(OnPropertyCondition.java:91) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnPropertyCondition.java:55) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 73 common frames omitted


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
```

**Update**: Add `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)` on this test class to overcome this barrier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are defining `junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default=per_class` in your `junit-platform.properties`. Setting this back to `per_method` or just delete the line would fix your problem.

Testcontainers JUnit extension does not really play well with this setting if you do not start to take control over the container lifecycle by yourself.
But mixing with with the strict restriction of having a `static` method for the `@DynamicPropertySource` would require to start the container upfront the properties registration. This looks, at least to me, not ideal for a clean test structure.

Comment: Removing `@Container` and calling `neo4jContainer.start()` from `neo4jProperties` would work too

Comment: Yes (you know this best ;) ) this was what I tried to say with the second last sentence. But his ends in "the last sentence". So you do not get a clean separation in the test between Testcontainers and Spring Boot infrastructure setup.

Comment: @bsideup The [Spring blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/27/dynamicpropertysource-in-spring-framework-5-2-5-and-spring-boot-2-2-6) about this also shows using `@Container`. Are you saying that it is best to avoid using `@Container` with `@DynamicPropertySource` ?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe it depends on your use case. If you want to have a "global" resource, not bounded to test's lifecycle, and reuse it between tests (in the same session), then you call `.start()` manually. There is nothing wrong about `@Container`, if/when you need it.

Comment: But [the docs](https://www.testcontainers.org/test_framework_integration/junit_5/) state: "The extension finds all fields that are annotated with @Container and calls their container lifecycle methods (methods on the Startable interface). Containers declared as static fields will be shared between test methods." So if it is a static field, they are already shared ?